# Android: can't decide how to manage background task

Tags: android, service, background, android-asynctask

I have a task which I need to run in the background in my Android app. It reads data over the network and populates a database. It can take several minutes to run.

Once it's started, it needs to complete successfully without interruption. (Otherwise I'll end up with a broken half-populated database.) I realise I can never guarantee it will *always* complete, but I want to make it as hard as possible for the system to kill off this task. For safety I guess I will have it populate a temporary database, and then only swap out the old database for the new one on successful completion of the import.

It's a modal operation; it does not make sense for the user to be interacting with the app while the import is in progress.

My first attempt is using an ASyncTask with a Progress dialog to achieve the modality, but this obviously breaks the "don't interrupt" requirement. I could work around the screen-rotation issue with ASyncTasks, but I don't think that goes far enough.

At the moment I'm not sure if this should be an ASyncTask, a Service, an IntentService, some combination of these, or something else entirely. Can you help me decide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off with services in that case. The Android runtime will leave it alone working as long as enough memory is available. In the case it kills the service, you can save the state in a bundle, and the system will restart the process as soon as possible, so you can resume the process, if possible for your solution:

[Android Fundamentals, Service Section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)

Then it is easy to communicate with the service, like showing the progress/ notifications etc, using a handle registry like proposes by [Mark Bredy in his Android Service Prototype](https://github.com/zedray/Android-Framework-Prototype)

Comment: I appreciate a Service is better for keeping the task alive, but it's not clear to me how I'd go about achieving modality, or displaying the progress dialog, in the Service scenario.

Comment: Well i'm not sure what you mean by modality, however have a look at the github hosted project from Mark Bredy, he shows a very neat architecture to handle servil modes of interaction with a service, like from an activity or by notifying the user. In general communication via Handlers will do the job.

Comment: By modality, I mean the user should not be able to interact with the app until the operation completes. From the user's point of view it is very much a blocking/foreground operation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd run it as a service and additionally I'd also have a clean SQLite DB on my server populated with the data the clients are going to retrieve so I can generate a kind of signature. Have the clients check for the correct signature of the DB. If the signature is not matching the servers signature then reinitialize the database filling process.

This is just an idea tho. I have no idea whether it'd be possible with what you are trying to do or not.